# Has composer global path changed (from 1.x to 2.0)

Tags: composer-php

I recently upgraded `composer` to the new version (on a `Ubuntu 18.04` machine) and everything seemed to work fine until I tried to `composer global require` a package. It was installed correctly but when I tried to call it, my bash says `command not found` (I had some globally installed packages before and they were working as expected)

After some digging, I found that my new package was not installed in `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` (this was part of my `$PATH`) but rather in `$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin`.

My question is : does the new version use a different directory for installing global packages (I couldn't find anything in the docs or any other online resource about that) or is something wrong with my setup ? (if so how can I track it down ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to find out would be using the **config** command:

`composer global config --list` and look for `bin-dir`

Or as a one liner if you prefer:
`composer global config --list | grep bin-dir`

Comment: Thank you this is the correct answer and yes the default path changed.